# sorting a 2D double array

Tags: java, sorting, matrix, double

I try to sort a 2D double array (double[][]) on the first value.
example: {1.0226342823592962,0.0}, {1.0395582845873155,1.0}
starting with the biggest value.
This is the code I use (java generated half of it)

```
java.util.Arrays.sort(indexMatrix, new java.util.Comparator<double[]>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(double[] o1, double[] o2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }


    });
```

However my 'indexMatrix' is not changed after. I think it has something to do with public int compare, because the values are so close to each other, if you cast them to int they will all be 1 and cannot be sorted. Or is it something else?

Comment: Is this your complete code? If yes then it will not be sorted because your `compare` method returns always `0` which means that the elements are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you cast them to integers? Just use [`Double.compareTo(Double)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#compareTo%28java.lang.Double%29) method in your sort method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    double[][] indexMatrix = new double[][] {
                  new double[] { 1.02, 100 }, 
                  new double[] { 1.03, 123 },
                  new double[] { 1.01, 321 } };

    Arrays.sort(indexMatrix, new Comparator<double[]>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(double[] o1, double[] o2) {
            return Double.compare(o2[0], o1[0]);
        }
    });

    for (double[] d : indexMatrix)
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(d));
}
```

Outputs:

```
[1.03, 123.0]
[1.02, 100.0]
[1.01, 321.0]
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement the compare method, what you have there is just a template. It is unchanged because return 0 by default means the compared values are equal. Other return values are -1 and +1, based on the actual situation.

Comment: the return values may be positive or negative. I can also return `-200` instead of `-1`.

Comment: Yes there is no constraint as to the actual value, other than it's signal.

Comment: Indeed, I forgot to put code there. (The automated code is not complete haha)

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't cast your doubles to integers. An `int` is just what `compare()` expects as a return parameter. It should return 0 if `o1` and `o2` are equal, a value less than 0 if `o1 < o2` and a value greater than 0 if `o1 > o2`.
You can just use [`Double.compare()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#compare%28double,%20double%29) for that:

```
java.util.Arrays.sort(indexMatrix, new java.util.Comparator<double[]>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(double[] o1, double[] o2) {
        // note that o2 comes first here to sort in descending order
        return Double.compare(o2[0], o1[0]);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

With Java8+

```
Arrays.sort(indexMatrix, (Double[] o1, Double[] o2) -> Double.compare(o1[0], o2[0]));
```